# Create function out of the axios POST that can reused later

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, axios, undefined

I have an `axios.POST` that I want to reuse in my code. the `then` part of my code will be different but when I add the `POST` part of the code to a function, I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

My code:

```
const myFunc = (query, variables) => {
  axios.post(
    "https://test.com/graphql",
    {
      query: query,
      variables: variables,
    },
    {
      headers: headers,
    }
  );
};
myFunc(myQuery, {
  id: "12345",
  nm: "TEST",
}).then((res) => console.log(res.data.data));
```

Is there a way for me to reuse `myFunc` without getting an `undefined` error?

Comment: Typo: You forgot your `return` statement in `myFunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise?retiredLocale=de) because an instance of a `Promise` will have the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method which you want to call.

The easiest way to do this is by just returning the `Promise` axios will be returning.

```js
const myFunc = (query, variables) => {
  return axios.post(
    "https://test.com/graphql",
    {
      query: query,
      variables: variables,
    },
    {
      headers: headers,
    }
  );
};
myFunc(myQuery, {
  id: "12345",
  nm: "TEST",
}).then((res) => console.log(res.data.data));
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to return in your post request

```
const myFunc = (query, variables) => {
  return axios.post(
    "https://test.com/graphql",
    {
      query: query,
      variables: variables,
    },
    {
      headers: headers,
    }
  );
};
myFunc(myQuery, {
  id: "12345",
  nm: "TEST",
}).then((res) => console.log(res.data.data));
```